# Is there a Model First ASP.core framework for creating razor Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have been exploring MVC frameworks to create a webapp. One way I thought of reducing duplicated code is to keep everything model first (draws from EF Code first). I want to include as much meta data as possible in the model class. Using generic repositories (this part I have handled) I can manage most of DB operations through a one or two repositories behind a factory.

Now, Extending this to Razor Views. Basically, Attributes define the View such as Form layout, Type of component, Component Provider (3P or OpenSource), along with native System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. A ComponentView Factory gets the right generic view template. The generic view template uses Reflection to then create generic CRUD views that largely fit for 90% of the use cases.

Does such a framework exist? Does this seem like a good approach?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Unfortunately, it's not a question that's well suited for Stack Overflow, as it's a) asking for software recommendations, and b) trying to assess whether an approach is good. Both tend to lead to opinion based answers.

Comment: That said, I'm not aware of any such frameworks, though I've implemented somewhat similar concepts. You can obviously use Visual Studio to generate views for CRUD operations based on a model, but that's a design-time approach, whereas you are looking for a runtime approach.

Comment: Aside, there _used_ to be a neat project, [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/cc488545(v=vs.100)), which would dynamically generate a templated website with CRUD operations based on a LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework model, relying on view templates and model annotations to customize the interface. It was a handy project—but, unfortunately, not one that Microsoft continued to invest into or maintain.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Going through the dynamic data and your comment was validation enough. I took the time and created a library that allows a model to be rendered n ways with attributes and reflection.